# Any resources or books to build VNC client

Tags: java, html5, canvas

I am very interested in network programming and I want to build a VNC client for fun and for learning purposes. I have been Googling for resources about VNC client and server, but most of time, resources found were about how to use VNC not how to build or how it actually works in business layer so I can get an idea about how it could be simulated. Please suggest me any documentation / articles / resources related to this. Thanks in advance.

It is my first post on Programmers Stackexchange site so please forgive me if this question is not appropriate for topic of this site.

Comment: Actually this is a good question, I'd be interested in answer too.

Comment: I just noticed @dirmitris fixed some syntax error in my writing. Thank you for that. I hope someone can answer my question at the end =D..

Comment: @ClementHerreman If you like a question you can upvote it, this will cause the question to show up more and get more attention and also rewards the author for coming up with the question. VNC runs on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://engineering.linkedin.com/javascript/vncjs-how-build-javascript-vnc-client-24-hour-hackday) takes you through the process of implementing the RFB protocol and what nots. It even has diagrams and Github hosted source code. [NoVNC](http://kanaka.github.com/noVNC/) is another open source project with Github code. A [small swarm](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/) of git tutorials is available if you've never used it.

There's also the [libVNCServer/LibVNCClient](http://libvncserver.sourceforge.net/) which is C based code for insertion into other things.